# Unable to get Mellanox ConnectX-3 to work with transceiver/cable

Tags: networking, linux-networking, infiniband

I'm attempting to upgrade my local network setup to 40G but I seem to have hit a snag. I have Mellanox ConnectX-3 VPI CX353A network cards I got off [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/182861791754), updated their firmware and installed their drivers. After switching transceivers/cable and buying a tool to re-code the cables I'm still unable to find the problem. I believe the issue lies in the drivers, they see the transceiver is connected but seem to be unwilling to use it.

My hardware:

https://pastebin.com/ucdYv1rb

MLNX OFED Driver version: 4.9-3.1.5

Network cables/Transceivers:

https://www.fs.com/products/30775.html

https://www.fs.com/products/69907.html

Customized to work with my MikroTik CRS354-48G-4S+2Q+RM Switch. I can change what vendor the cables should work with, I have the re-coding tool for FS cables.

Outputs of various InfiniBand commands I found: https://pastebin.com/8ZWb7wjb

Output of ethtool -m

```
root@testserver:/home/test# ethtool -m enp1s0
        Identifier                                : 0x0d (QSFP+)
        Extended identifier                       : 0x00
        Extended identifier description           : 1.5W max. Power consumption
        Extended identifier description           : No CDR in TX, No CDR in RX
        Extended identifier description           : High Power Class (> 3.5 W) not enabled
        Connector                                 : 0x23 (No separable connector)
        Transceiver codes                         : 0x08 0x00 0x30 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x80 0xd5
        Transceiver type                          : 40G Ethernet: 40G Base-CR4
        Transceiver type                          : SAS 6.0G
        Transceiver type                          : SAS 3.0G
        Transceiver type                          : FC: short distance (S)
        Transceiver type                          : FC: Twin Axial Pair (TW)
        Transceiver type                          : FC: 1200 MBytes/sec
        Transceiver type                          : FC: 800 MBytes/sec
        Transceiver type                          : FC: 400 MBytes/sec
        Transceiver type                          : FC: 200 MBytes/sec
        Transceiver type                          : FC: 100 MBytes/sec
        Encoding                                  : 0x00 (unspecified)
        BR, Nominal                               : 10300Mbps
        Rate identifier                           : 0x00
        Length (SMF,km)                           : 0km
        Length (OM3 50um)                         : 0m
        Length (OM2 50um)                         : 0m
        Length (OM1 62.5um)                       : 0m
        Length (Copper or Active cable)           : 1m
        Transmitter technology                    : 0xa0 (Copper cable unequalized)
        Attenuation at 2.5GHz                     : 8db
        Attenuation at 5.0GHz                     : 11db
        Attenuation at 7.0GHz                     : 0db
        Attenuation at 12.9GHz                    : 0db
        Vendor name                               : FS
        Vendor OUI                                : 00:40:20
        Vendor PN                                 : QSFP-PC01
        Vendor rev                                : A
        Vendor SN                                 : MT1422VS08180
        Date code                                 : 190228
        Revision Compliance                       : Revision not specified
        Module temperature                        : 0.00 degrees C / 32.00 degrees F
        Module voltage                            : 0.0000 V
```

Output of ethtool:

```
root@testserver:/home/test# ethtool enp1s0
Settings for enp1s0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKX4/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
                                56000baseCR4/Full
                                56000baseSR4/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKX4/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000014 (20)
                               link ifdown
        Link detected: no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Auto-negotiation was turned off on my switch and had manufacturer's recommend settings for a 40G connection. Turning auto-negotiation on solved the issue.

I want to answer my question with details from my adventure down this path on getting my 40 gigabit network setup. This way anyone else who tries this in the future has some reference points.

I think it's important to note I used my 40G NIC in Ethernet mode, not Infiniband. The Ethernet drivers did seem to work, but I ended on the OFED drivers because it worked I didn't want to mess with it anymore. If you plan on getting a setup like this, **make sure** your card is capable of Ethernet mode!

#### What I tried

Once I got the switch, NICs and cables I installed the OFED (OpenFabrics Enterprise Distribution) drivers/software provided by Mellanox/Nvidia. Once those failed to establish a link I used the tools built into the software to update their firmware. It was rather simple, only issue I had was finding the latest firmware .bin file for my specific cards. The firmware I used was 2.33.5000, still quite old but newer than what was on the cards.

After that failed I assumed the cables/transceivers (one unit) were the culprit. I swapped out the cables I had originally gotten for a pair ([56G 10m AOC](https://www.fs.com/products/71512.html) + [56G 2m DAC](https://www.fs.com/products/70781.html) > [40G 11m AOC](https://www.fs.com/products/30775.html) + [40G 1m DAC](https://www.fs.com/products/69907.html)) of customized cables that were designed for the specific Mikrotik switch I had bought. Since these were customized, they took a month to arrive. Once these arrived and did not work I was stumped and proceeded to seek help on various forums. Before long it was suggested I [purchase a tool](https://www.fs.com/products/96657.html) from FS.com that would allow me to re-code the vendor on the transceivers to hopefully trick the NIC into working.

Since the cables were customized for the switch, I assumed it was the NIC that wasn't cooperating. Setting the transceiver to either IBM or Mellanox didn't work. After seeking further assistance a couple people suggested I find documentation on the NICs and find compatible cables/transceivers. I did find a PDF (although not provided or made by IBM/Mellanox) that listed some compatible part numbers that FS.com provided. So I purchased the [IBM 49Y7890 1m DAC](https://www.fs.com/products/36302.html) from FS.com.

Once it arrived I found this was not the solution either. Out of desperation I found a few threads of people that have flashed their cards to true Mellanox firmware. I decided to try my hand at it. After some troubleshooting on getting the updater to work, I successfully flashed firmware version 2.42.5000 with new PSID of MT_1100120019 (See 'This wasn't the end of it' paragraph 4 for details about how this can mess up things. [See here for how to cross flash](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/flashing-stock-mellanox-firmware-to-oem-emc-connectx-3-ib-ethernet-dual-port-qsfp-adapter.20525/#post-198015)). After this attempt failed, further discussions took place on the issue and eventually concluded I should test the NICs directly connected to one another. Once I got the NICs connected to together and setup their subnet, I saw speeds of 36.5GBit/s using several iperf tests (since iperf and iperf3 are single threaded you will need to setup multiple for these speeds. I setup 16 each set to use 10 threads). Once I eliminated the NICs from the list of culprits I started to wonder if the auto-negotiation setting on the switch would have been an issue. Turning it back on I immediately saw 'link ok'.

#### This wasn't the end of it

I had gotten the setup to work, turns out there was no compatibility issue and I likely never needed to swap out my cables or buy the IBM one. I was ecstatic but this was far from over. I had intended to run this setup with Proxmox on my server and Windows as a client machine. Both of these systems would be equipped with 40G.

Since I knew I was going to mess up the Proxmox install several times, I first backed up everything to another drive. Once done I proceeded to install the Mellanox OFED drivers on Proxmox. There is a couple issues with trying this, the OFED drivers try to remove very critical packages from Proxmox since they 'interfere' with the drivers (they don't). So I edited the mlnxofedinstaller script and commented out all calls to the 'remove_old_packages' function. This prevented the installer from giving Proxmox a lobotomy.

At this point most things worked, the only issue I was having was sending data to the server. It wasn't accepting any more than a few megabytes per second, far less than I should be getting. I tried many different versions of the software, trying the Ubuntu 20.04, 19.XX didn't work because of dependencies that Proxmox doesn't have but those two installs do. I was forced to install Ubuntu 18.04 drivers since these were the latest drivers without dependency issues. Installing the drivers typically didn't solve the speed issue. So I tried to install kernel packages only using the `--kernel-only` flag on the installer. At some point I had gotten the speeds I was looking for, but this was a fluke as I wasn't able to replicate them later. I decided to try some variation of the Debian 10 drivers, got slightly better speeds at 20MB/s. After some time bouncing ideas off someone else, I tried setting the 40G network to 9000 MTU. This lead to some seriously odd results. Speeds of barely 1 gigabit even though the entire setup had MTU of 9000. I switched it back to 1500 to do further testing on Ubuntu instead of Proxmox, since I had good speeds on Ubuntu. This failed to come through, the speed tests I ran originally must've been a fluke.

I decided to swap the NICs in the systems, labeling them 1 and 2 after I took them out so I didn't get them confused. After running more speed tests, it turns out the card in the Proxmox system was the issue. I was able to send at full speed, but not able to receive at full speed. I recalled the drivers updating the firmware on that NIC and didn't think much of it since I was using the latest version. So I re-flashed the cross flashed version I had originally installed. After further testing we concluded the limited speeds of 22GBit/s up and 11GBit/s down were the result of various bottle necks between the systems. Specifically testing on RAM disks with a 30 gibibyte file, we concluded the server with twice the DIMMs populated was able to write at twice the speed. Attempting to use the NVMe with a NTFS file system on the test system did poorly due to the compatibility layer being single threaded. After running a dozen more iperf tests, everything was running smoothly, even with the server running Proxmox.

A caveat when using the OFED drivers, you will lose the ability to connect to CIFS network shares. The OFED drivers unload this module until the driver is no longer running. The Ethernet drivers work but it may be necessary to cross flash to mellanox firmware.

#### The route ahead

Since I was on a budget of about $1,500, I had to go with some of the cheapest equipment I could find. Hence the $60 network cards. When I found this Mikrotik switch new for $500 I was stoked. It had all I needed for the best price I could find, even beating some used units. It didn't have port licensing and came with one of the top tier software licenses. It was really a hard deal to beat. Of course everything comes with compromises.

Even though I didn't really intend to use the 10G SFP+ ports, I wanted them for future expansion. I had gotten a SFP+ to RJ45 adapter and a 10G NIC so I had something to test while the 40G equipment was in shipping. I was able to receive a total of 2 gigabits per second on the 10G NIC. This was all the data I could feed it between my 1 gigabit internet connection and my 1 gigabit equipped server. But attempting to run a gigabit upload to the internet from the 10G card resulting in much lower speeds than I was expecting. I was only getting around 300Mbps despite quite reliably being able to hit 900Mbps. I proceeded to ask around and the theory of the switch not having the buffer size to drop 10G to 1G was the conclusion. This theory is furthered by switching the 1G uplink of my router to the 10G port and attempting to upload at gigabit from a 40G system (only a 4x drop, instead of a 10x) dropped the speeds down to ~1mbps. Which suggests the 48 1G ports have a shared buffer.

This isn't really an issue for my Windows machine, since I never upload at those speeds anyway. But for my server this is a pretty big deal. Having the upload bandwidth chopped to a third could end up being a real issue. After digging around some I found I could use routing metrics to force traffic through either the 40G NIC or the 1G NIC depending on where it's going. While this solution isn't 100% perfect, it still works quite well.

Using the `route -n` command I'm able to see my current route paths. The goal is to modify the routes so the 40G is preferred for local connections and 1G is preferred for internet connections. The higher the metric on the route, the more expensive it is to use, so the system will use the least expensive route.

Proxmox ships with ifupdown by default, it's more stable and has more features. Netplan can add routes, but can't remove or modify them. It also doesn't allow you to run commands before, on or after interface start. You *can* use netplan, but you would need to setup a separate service to remove/modify additional routes.

This is my current `/etc/network/interfaces` config, I had to add the post-up commands to my NICs to add the routes in;

```
auto ens18              # 1 Gigabit NIC
iface ens18 inet static
        ...
        post-up /usr/sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 metric 1000 ens18

auto ens19              # 40 Gigabit NIC
iface ens19 inet static
        ...
        post-up /usr/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 192.168.0.1 metric 1000 ens19
        post-up /usr/sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 metric 1 ens19
        post-up /usr/sbin/route del -net 192.168.0.0/24 metric 0 ens19
```

Your routes should look like;

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 ens18
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1000   0        0 ens19
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 ens19
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1000   0        0 ens18
```

Obviously these interfaces will need to be on different local IPs, I suggest using the IP set to the 40G NIC for anything local. If something needs to be port forwarded, use the gigabit NIC. It should be alright to use gigabit NIC locally as long as you aren't sending more than 100MB at a time. This routing can work if you send 40 gigabits/s local data to the IP bound to the gigabit port, it's not always consistent though.

It's important to note if you're modifying a route, you should add the modified version before you remove the old version.
It's also important to note that your setup may not need the exact same as I posted above. For example my Proxmox install already adds a route for ens18 so I would need to remove that after I added the one I wanted.

And that's it! I have finally gotten my setup completed with the speeds I wanted. I'm able to transfer to my server at about 1.7GB/s and from at about 1GB/s (limitation being either NTFS or one of the SSDs).

Comment: I really appreciate you doing the writeup here and even though not much useful content on this topic can be found on serverfault, your post here is one exception. I too am setting up MCX3 networking with my 5950X workstation, and so far I am eschewing the switch, not to mention a 40Gbit switch would not be affordable or quiet enough for me to practically deploy. I actually have been thinking that slotting multiple CX3 cards into another machine of mine and using that machine as a switch would be a reasonable path forward.

Comment: Recently I found out about the inclusion of an mlx5 driver bundled with macOS so I'm now able to run 20Gbit by connecting a CX4 100Gb card to my M1 Max Macbook Pro. However there is one serious issue with this right now that I am having trouble resolving, which is after I disconnect the USB-C cable to this thunderbolt enclosure that the CX4 card is set up in from my macbook, after about a few hours (e.g. overnight), reconnecting it will NOT re-enable my fiber link. It kind of seems like some kind of stupid power saving behavior. I tried stuff like removing the PCI device, and

Comment: rescanning to bring the network adapter back on the linux side, and *neither* this nor rebooting the machine will bring the connection back. The only thing that brings it back is *physically unplugging and replugging the transceiver* at the linux workstation. This, obviously, is a nonstarter. I am curious if you encountered or know anything about this. My suspicion is that maybe if we can find a driver hacking wizard they may be able to make headway into it but other than that it's a fat chance since this equipment was not designed for these kind of use cases. I had similar problems with

Comment: connecting to a windows PC in this same exact fashion. If I let the windows PC sleep or hibernate for too long, e.g. overnight, I have to replug the fiber transceiver at the Linux end to get the fiber connection enabled again. Since I care a bit more at the moment about the macOS reconnection side of this problem I think I may have a funny workaround for the time being. Since the link appears to reliably work and reconnect so long as it doesn't disconnect for hours, the desk I've got this set up at also has an old iMac on it, I will try to plug it into the iMac to have it keep the link alive.